# Calling the method in HomeController via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to make an ajax request from a view that is in the following way:

```
C:\Users\Programmer\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RatingCandidate\RatingCandidate\Views\Home\Index.aspx
```

and that ajax request is trying to call a method that is in HomeController in this way:

```
C:\Users\Senior\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RatingCandidate\RatingCandidate\Controllers\HomeController.cs
```

In view I'm basically calling the function in onclick button:

```
<input type="button" style="width: 100px; height: 30px;" value="Enviar" runat="server" onclick="SendEmail()" />
```

and the ajax:

```
function SendEmail() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Controllers/HomeController/SendEmail',
        type: 'POST',
        //data: { className: cName },// Your parameter
        success: function (result) {
            // What you want to do after the call
        }
    });
};
```

and HomeController is attempting to receive as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendEmail()
{
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I believe it is my inattention, but do not know where, does anyone have any idea where he might be the error?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need to search for is routing in MVC.

You don't call your controllers like you would invoke a file or something. Virtual path to your controller class has nothing to do with a path to your `.cs` file containing that class.

Default routings are defined like: `{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}` (where `Id` id optional), so to call your controller, you should make a call to `Home/SendEmail` (controller name is by default taken without `Controller` suffix).

Please take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing

Comment: Hey thanks man, I created a routing for the method and it worked.